# %s Not Replacing Information

Tags: python, string

I am trying to put information available on the web, and to do so I am using string formatting:

```
fields = """{"fname" : %s, "lname" : %s, "email" : %s, "deptid" : deptid, "active" : active, "sentient" : sentient}""", (fname, lname, email)
```

with various values for each of the three variables.

Anyway, when I try to view fields, it still shows the %s! How do I actually make it replace it?

Comment: odd, I thought I tried that, and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you are looking for is %, not ,.
as in `fields = """{"fname" : %s, "lname" : %s, "email" : %s, "deptid" : deptid, "active" : active, "sentient" : sentient}""" % (fname, lname, email)`

Answer (score 2):

```
fields = """{"fname" : %s, "lname" : %s, "email" : %s, "deptid" : deptid, "active" : active, "sentient" : sentient}""" % (fname, lname, email)
```

Quite simply, replace your comma (which constructs a tuple) with a `%` (which is the operator which does string formatting).

Also, I would recommend replacing your triple quotes with single quotes (although it's not wrong the way you have it. I just find it's more readable this way).

```
fields = '{"fname" : %s, "lname" : %s, "email" : %s, "deptid" : deptid, "active" : active, "sentient" : sentient}' % (fname, lname, email)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `%` operator at all, but rather use a simple `,`, constructing a tuple instead.

```
fields = ("""{"fname" : %s, "lname" : %s, "email" : %s, "deptid" : deptid, """
          """"active" : active, "sentient" : sentient}""" % (fname, lname, email))
```

Anyway, seems like you are trying to generate JSON output.  In case you are, have a look at the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `%` operator to bind the list of variables to the string, like this:

```
"Here is my %s" % ( "string" )
```

You've got a comma between the string and your list of variables, which doesn't really get you anything.